# wrong usage of pthread_create?

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to understand if my approach may result in undefined behavior.

I have allocated 10 elements of my structure using calloc in this manner:

```
struct myStructure {
    int index;
    int myNum;
    char myLetter[1024];
    void *udata;
};

static void *threads(void *thread_data) {
    struct myStructure *arg = (struct myStructure*)thread_data;
}

struct myStructure *elements = (struct myStructure *)calloc(10, sizeof(*elements));
pthread_t *pthread_e = calloc(10, sizeof(*pthread_e));

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    elements[i].index = i;
    pthread_create(&pthread_e[i], NULL, threads, (void *)&elements[i]);
    pthread_detach(pthread_e[i]);
}
```

If the threads attempt to access each other's thread_data using pointer arithmetic and modify data such as '`myNum`', '`myLetter`', or '`udata`', would it cause problems or violate the restrict rules (note: I plan to use mutex/spinlocks during modification)?
I ask because the last argument I provide to pthread_create - `(void *)&elements[i]` - is defined as `void *restrict arg`.

I hope someone can help me to understand and also confirm if what i'm doing is wrong

Comment: "defined as void *restrict arg." Where do you get that? POSIX says nothing about `restrict`.

Comment: i'm using Mac, but according to this: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I was looking at an old version of POSIX docs. The newer one does say `restrict` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `pthread_create` has `restict`-qualified parameters is to ensure that the function can assume that the thread handle or attributes aren't passed along as the callback arg parameter. Since `arg` is `void*`, the function cannot assume that this is not the case unless `restrict` is added. This is some manner of micro-optimization of internals in the pthread library and won't affect the application unless you are doing really strange things there.

As far as pointer aliasing goes, you point to a region returned from malloc/calloc and it has no "effective type" yet - it won't get that until the first access. And that doesn't matter here either, as long as you only ever access it through a `struct myStructure*` pointer.

So nope, no problems with pointer aliasing here. The only thing which is undefined behavior is the lack of a `return` statement in your callback. Normal thread safety concerns do of course also apply - you may need to protect against race conditions etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for a thoroughly answered response and comprehensive explanations; it truly merits commendation.